# Play Framework specs2 Fails to Fail

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I have an interesting problem with testing using the WithApplication scope from Play 2.1.1.

Here is my code:

```
import play.api.test.{FakeApplication, WithApplication}
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class TestSpec extends Specification {

  "Test" should {
    "fail" in {
      true === false
    }

    "fail as well" in new WithApplication() {
      true === false
    }

    "fail with extreme prejudice" in new WithApplication(FakeApplication()) {
      true === false
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect all 3 of these to fail but in this case only the first one failed.

```
[info] Total for specification TestSpec
[info] Finished in 21 ms
[info] 3 examples, 1 failure, 0 error
[info]
[error] Failed: : Total 4, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 3, Skipped 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error] TestSpec
```

Is there some trick I'm missing here?

I'm using Scala 2.10.2, sbt 0.12.2, Play 2.1.1 and runnning on Java 7 U40.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try a latest version of Play or the latest version of specs2 (2.2.3) where this issue has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. Upgrading all my production services is a bit extreme but will investigate. Been wanting to find an excuse. :-)

Comment: Stuck with Play 2.1.1 and updated Specs2 to 2.2.3 and it fixed the problem. Cheers.